# HTML/CSS: How do i make images from my website appear in other websites?

Tags: html, css

I have my own website and i have images stored, but when i try to share them on posts on websites like leagueoflegends.com the link shows but not the image, this happens in all the websites im trying to post my pictures in, i use the image links too: http://www.adanyeva.org/statistics.html? (takes you to an image but it never shows when you share the link).

```
<p>﻿<img alt="" src="/Assets/download.png" style="width: 1400px; height: 260px;" /></p>
```

this is the code for that image, not sure what's going on.

summary: trying to get my personal website's image url so that when i paste it's link in other websites, i get the preview of that image.

Comment: /Assets/download.png is the relative path. you also need the www.myWebSite.com before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have give absolute URL like below when you refer from other sites:

```
<p>﻿<img alt="" src="http://www.adanyeva.org/Assets/download.png" style="width: 1400px; height: 260px;" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

its because the website you are trying to show image on, does not get the image. because the path that you are giving will only work for your site, you need to give the proper link. 
something like:

```
  <p>﻿<img alt="" src="www.yourwebsite.com/Assets/download.png" style="width: 1400px; height: 260px;" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the absolute url of your image.
check the snippet below.

```html
<p>﻿<img alt="" src="http://www.adanyeva.org/Assets/download.png" style="width: 1400px; height: 260px;" /></p>
```